# SQLServer using GETDATE() as a parameter of table function in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query:

```
select * from dbo.GetTableTest(GETDATE(), GETDATE());

select * from dbo.GetTableTest('2020-02-02', '2020-02-02');
```

first one gives syntax error: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '('.`. Second query gives no error.
My complete example function header:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


--##
alter FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTableTest]
(
@dataod datetime,
@datado datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE
as return
select
fo.DNRWGKONTR NrFaktury,cast(fo.DWPLYNELO as DATETIME) DataWplywuFaktury
FROM
PEVREJVATZAKUP1 fo
where
cast(fo.DDATA as DATETIME) between @dataod and @datado
```

I've try many variations but the result is the same. How can I write this kind of query using some date functions as a parameters?

Comment: @deHaar - how is that different from the very first code sample in the question?

Comment: I rebuild your code and i get no error... sorry!
can you show your table values as examples

Comment: Solution I've found, use declaration rather than function in parameters. ```declare @d1 datetime;
declare @d2 datetime;
set @d1=dbo.first_day(year(getdate()),month(getdate()));
set @d2=dbo.last_day(year(getdate()),month(getdate()));
select * from dbo.GetTableTest(@d1, @d2);``` it works.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You cannot use
`...MyFunction( SELECT GETDATE())`

Use instead:
`...MyFunction(GETDATE())`

---

Old answer:

Remove the comma on your function declaration:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction]
(   
    @dataod datetime, -- <- only one param, only use a comma here if you have more than one params
) -- <- this is the bracket which causes your error
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT @dataod AS DateValue
)
GO
```

Fix:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction]
(   
    @dataod datetime
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT @dataod AS DateValue
)
GO
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM MyFunction(GETDATE())
```

Output:

```
DateValue
2020-10-01 10:13:59.957
```

Comment: IT was just a sample there was more than one parameter. It is not a solution.

Comment: @fox can't fix code that cannot be seen. Make an effort to provide appropriate context and a complete signature of your function.

Comment: @fox you're funny, how should i know that, if you did not post your whole code?
Here you have only one parameter in your function...